# ** Error 503: Need help

Tags: fatal-error

I was adding a new magento extension to our website. 
After the install, this error happened.

[image: Error:50x]

The website and admin panel is now unusable.
We need to get our website back up ASAP.

Why did this error happen ?

And is this bad ?

Is there an easy fix ?

I am not very good at web, so any information and support would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the content of the most recent file under your var/report folder please ?

Comment: Please check maintenance.flag are created  at  your application and if edit then just delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be numerous things, but it's best to look into your magento root directory, and see if there's a file called maintenance.flag   if it's there, you can either delete it, or wait until the extension is done installing

Comment: All i did was delete the maintenance.flag Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

This information is insuffient to help you out. Please debug your store as per **[this guide lines](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/30183/3535)** and come again with specific error that you are getting in the `var/log` directory.

Since it is almost sure the problems comes from the extension, the primary thing you need to do is temporally disable that extension. You can do this by

`app\etc\modules\{Extensionnamespace_Extensionname}.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <{Extensionnamespace_Extensionname}>
            <active>false</active>
        </{Extensionnamespace_Extensionname}>
    </modules>
</config>
```

You need to put `false` inside `active` node and then delete `var/cache` folder.